# Use converter standalone repeatedly

Tags: vmware-converter

I need to do an conversion P2V every 3 months from the same physical 2 servers to an virtuel test environment.
Is that possible with de free version converter starter?

Thanks
Jos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Yes it is.

Comment: +1 because it just made me laugh this morning and I needed it.

Comment: I love that the 15-chat min limit forces you to be creative if it's a one-word-answer. I once responded to someone "yes, plus some mandatory spacing" and they came back to me to ask about what type of spacing they should use :)